# AES_GCM encryption using webcrypto API

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes-gcm, webcrypto-api

I came across an AES_GCM implementation whose encrypt function is as follows:

```
async function encryptMessage(key){
    let encodedMessage = encodeMessage();
    cipherText = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "AES-GCM",
            iv: window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12))
        },
        key,
        encodedMessage
    );
    let buffer = new Uint8Array(cipherText, 0, 5);
    console.log(buffer);
    console.log(btoa(buffer));
}
```

My question is, why

> new Uint8Array(cipherText, 0, 5);

has the parameters 0 and 5. I searched the internet and found that these parameters represent a view. But why only 0 and 5? Can we use numbers other than these?

Comment: Those numbers don't make sense to me. You'd have to ask the person who wrote that code. This doesn't look like good code since the IV is lost and you'd need that in order to decrypt it properly. Maybe somebody used AES_GCM as a poor mans hash function which it is not. This is just speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that example came from https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/web-crypto/encrypt-decrypt/aes-gcm.js, which is part of the MDN example.

My understanding is they are just showing the first few characters to the user, as proof it has been encrypted. You will see the real content is kept in `cipherText`, which along with `iv` is a module-level variable.